# Parse and Switch Elements of Folder Names using Powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell, rename

I have been trying to write a powershell script (my first) to

1. parse out only the folders within a directory
2. select only those folders matching a specific naming convention ('SEASON YEAR')
3. switch the order of the elements of the name ('YEAR SEASON')

I eventually used the program BulkRenameUtility to do this using the regexp ^(\w+) (\d+) and switching the token order to $2 $1 -- however, I still am learning Powershell and would like to be able to do this without using an external program.

So, to re-iterate, at C:\Users\Test

there are folders and files.. some of the folders are named `Spring 2015`, `Fall 2014`, for example. However, other folders have names such as `geogex`. Files have names such as `ENG1A SPRING 2015.odt`and `untitled_0.odt`.

How do I only change the names of the folders named like "Spring 2015" to read "2015 Spring", "2014 Fall" etc. ?

I was able to use

```
 gci | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | select-string -pattern '\d+'
```

to accomplish 1 and 2 but am stuck on using this to do part 3: actually rename by reversing the elements of the name. I tried putting the above within a variable and  like so:

```
gci | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | select-string -pattern '\d+' | %{$data = $_.line; Write-Output "$data"};
```

however, while the above outputs exactly the folders I want the array $data seems to only hold the last line of output. Such that:

```
gci | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | select-string -pattern '\d+' | %{$data = $_.line; Write-Output "$data"};
$data
```

will output:

```
test 123
test 321
test 321
```

I am unsure if this is even the a valid direction to begin with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Select-String`, use object's properties:

```
# Path to folder
$Path =  '.\'

# Regex to match 'SEASON YEAR' and extract capture groups
$Regex = '^(\w+)\s(\d+)'

# Get all objects in path
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path |
    # Select only objects that are directory and name matches regex
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match $Regex} |
        # For each such object
        ForEach-Object {
            # Generate new name
            $NewName = $_.Name -replace ($Regex, '$2 $1')

            # Rename object
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName
        }
```